# XS Project Share SAP HANA cannot see in browser

Tags: sapui5, hana, xsengine

I have project with XS project, I already shared to HANA packages but failed when show to browser, the error show:

404 - Not found
We could not find the resource you're trying to access.
It might be misspelled or currently unavailable.

My .xsaccess:

```
{
    "exposed" : true,
    "authentication" : [{"method":"Basic"}], 
    "cache_control" : "no-cache, no-store",
    "cors" : {
        "enabled" : false
    }
}
```

.xsapp:

```
{}
```

xsprivileges:

```
{
    "privileges" : [
        { "name" : "ProfileOwner", "description" : "Profile Ownership" }
    ]
}
```

and one question, is it possible the problem because the role user or privileges user, about authorization? How to fix this issue? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The .xsapp should be a empty file with no content in it. The exposed parameter in the .xsaccess should be enough to expose your project. Make sure that all files are activated in the HANA repository.

If the error was authorization specific you would get a 503 error. If the 404 error is a XSEngine page, either your code isn't activated or the package path is incorrect.

Comment: I also tried the .xsapp empty file, but I have same error. the all file already activated in SAP HANA reporsitory (with yellow icon in icon picture file)

Comment: The yellow icon represents an inactive object, the active object is green. You could probably right click on it & set it to the active version